# How to compile SQLite3 for Linux without warnings?

Tags: linux, sqlite

I am getting hundreds of these warnings when I compile my sqlite3.c file for linux.

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17134,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17137,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINCREMENT' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINCREMENT
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17140,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17143,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOMATIC_INDEX' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOMATIC_INDEX
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17146,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTORESET' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_AUTORESET
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17149,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOVACUUM' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOVACUUM
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17152,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_BETWEEN_OPTIMIZATION' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_BETWEEN_OPTIMIZATION
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17155,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_BLOB_LITERAL' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_BLOB_LITERAL
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17158,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_BTREECOUNT' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_BTREECOUNT
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17161,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_BUILTIN_TEST' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_BUILTIN_TEST
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17164,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_CAST' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_CAST
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):       ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17167,5):  warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_CHECK' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
```

Does anyone have any solution for this? I am not sure what I should be doing to not get these errors. It looks like the macros are showing up as not being defined. When I compile for windows I have absolutely no issues.

I have these three files (sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, and sqlite3ext.h):

```
https://gist.github.com/Bdoom/2956a03eb82fd21fcb279b1efcff5576
https://gist.github.com/Bdoom/0e7dd714bd626e3cdcde6443f46ac593
https://gist.github.com/Bdoom/f35a6455694db809967dd69e98d380b7
```

Comment: What command are you using to compile?

Comment: Looks like you're on windows, not linux

Comment: Yeah I'm using Unreal Engine 4, which uses a toolchain they created which lets you compile to linux. I would have asked on their website, however this is more of a general question I feel, maybe I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

> How to compile SQLite3 for Linux without warnings?

Here is the warning with line wrapping:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):
C:\Users\pbssu\Desktop\Plugins\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Source\SQLite3UE4Plugin\Private\sqlite3.c(17134,5):
warning: 'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux):   #if SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION
```

You should probably show the command line. You have several choices for this warning. You can add `-Wno-undef` to `CFLAGS` for `sqlite3.c`.

You can add `-DSQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION=0` to `CFLAGS` for `sqlite3.c`.

You can open `sqlite3.c` and add the following after the headers are included:

```
#ifndef SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION
# define SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION 0
#endif
```

Lather, rinse, repeat for the other defines.

---

> Comments] I'm not sure how much Linux C differs from windows c?

C is the same on Linux and Windows. The material differences are in the compiler and the OS's ABI.

> Comments] The warnings do not occur in windows.

Probably a different compiler. Are you using MSVC on Windows?

> Comments] Will these warnings affect actual performance of the file?

No. Any preprocessor symbol, like `SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION`, that is not defined evaluates to 0 when used numerically. It happened on WIndows too, but you were not aware of it.

> Comments] Will functions break and be unsuable?

Probably not.

> Comments] Or can I ignore these warnings?

I believe you can ignore them. You can do so with GCC using `-Wno-undef`.

> Comments] Are they important?

It depends or what you consider important. I don't think they are. To me this is just using standard C language features.

One thing you can do is file a bug against SQLite. They may look at it and say, "this is important because a lot of people may experience it. We should fix it in our sources so we don't get more bug reports like this".

Comment: Hey Jww, I opened the file and I found a lot of those #ifndef things. I'm not sure if it's just not recognizing it though? These files were directly taken from sqlite3 website. I'm not sure how much Linux C differs from windows c? The warnings do not occur in windows. Will these warnings affect actual performance of the file? Will functions break and be unsuable? Or can I ignore these warnings? Are they important?

Comment: Hey Jww. Thanks for the feedback. I will try and finish the entire compilation process and put my server on my linux instance and see if the sql function calls are still writing stuff to my database, reading.. and more. I just need to be able to still call SQL queries to insert data, and select data from the database.